# Adding Viewbag in Current view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to see if I can add a ViewBag to get another database result to a view list I already have. Below is where I am trying to do in the controller and view: Is this the correct approach?

Controller.cs:

```cs
    public ActionResult Branch(string Branch)
    {
        ViewBag.BranchName = Branch;
        var result = from c in db.Branches select c;
        ViewBag.Data1 = result;

        var employees = from m in db.Employees
                where m.Branch == Branch || Branch == null || Branch == "" select m;

        return View(employees.ToList());

    }
```

View.cshtml:

```cs
    ...

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Data1 as IEnumerable<Test.Models.Employee>)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name);
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Why do you have `var item in ViewBag.Data1 as IEnumerable<Test.Models.Employee>` in the view, are `Employees` and `Branches` extension of each other

Comment: Here is what I am trying to accomplish - When bringing back a list of employees (from a SQL database - this view is working correctly) I want to then display some information from a Branch database (1 record only as this is linked by the branch from employee table) in the same view. So I thought maybe I could use a Viewbag and tie the branch from the employees table to the branch from the branch table.

Comment: @EBaze If that's the case, you could probably get away with a JOIN to the Branches when you get the employee list. If you're using an ORM you can even make it do the work for you and just have a Branch navigation property on the Employee model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly store the result of your Linq query in a ViewBag variable and use it the same way you would use it in any other case.

The only snag you might run into with the code you provided is the compiler may not understand the `Employee` (or did you mean `Branch`, based on your code sample?) class.

To fix this you a few options:

- Update the Web.Config file in your Views directory so the `Test.Models` namespace is used when compiling all of your views:

  Views/Web.Config:

  ```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
      <pages ...>
          <namespaces>
              ...
              <add namespace="Test.Models" />
              ...
          </namespaces>
      </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  ```
- Add `@using Test.Models` to the top of views that need to use the namespace.
- Forget `ViewBag` entirely by strongly typing your view to a viewmodel class and put anything you need to access from the view in your viewmodel:

  ViewModel.cs (new):

  ```
  using Test.Models;

  namespace Test.ViewModels
  {
      public class BranchViewModel
      {
          public string BranchName { get; set; }

          List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

          List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
      }
  }
  ```

  Controller.cs (updated):

  ```
  using Test.ViewModels;
  using Test.Models;

  ...

  public ActionResult Branch(string Branch)
  {
     IEnumerable<Employee> employees = from m in db.Employees
                                       where m.Branch == Branch || Branch == null || Branch == ""
                                       select m;
     IEnumerable<Branches> branches = from c in db.Branches
                                      select c;


      var viewModel = new BranchViewModel()
      {
          BranchName = Branch,
          Employees = employees.ToList(),
          Branches = branches.ToList()
      };

      return View(viewModel);

  }
  ```

  View.cshtml (updated):

  ```
  @model Test.ViewModels.BranchViewModel

  ...

  @foreach (var branch in Model.Branches)
  {
      @Html.Display(branch.name)
  }

  ...
  ```